# How to download pip packages for a different operating system?

Tags: python, pip

I want to download `pip` packages so that later I could install it on a different machine (with a different OS). However the `--download` option downloads wheel files specific for the current OS.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following:

```
pip3 install --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
```

The `--only-binary=:all:` is required when specifying `--platform` (if you omit it there is another parameter you can specify instead) and the platform itself can be found by looking at PyPi at the files for the package in question (https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/7.2.0/#files for example) - the platform is the last part of the filename e.g. win32, manylinux1_x86_64, manylinux1_i686 etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip download --platform
```

is the answer. Google what platforms are available :)

Comment: Where did you get this info? It says it's not an option, and it's not listed in the `man` page either. `no such option: --platform`

Comment: @MichaelAltfield https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/#cmdoption-platform?

Answer (score 0):

go to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) download the packages you desire in one of the formats available and later copy and install them on the machine you want. 
Instalation method differ on the format, but are as simple as pip install.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtual environment using the `virtualenv` tool or a container using `docker` and ship this to your other OSes.

[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

You can create a python environment and install all of your python modules using pip and when you download it onto your other OS it will prepare the environment for you. You just need to download your virtualenv on the other machine and source your environment to get the same work environment.

[docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Alternatively you could use a container instead such as docker and pre-build an image of your software with all of the python modules packaged. You just need to download docker on the other machine and install your image to get the same work environment.

Comment: Nope, I don't think virtualenv can do that